# Generating dynamic data using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Given that I have an array of alphabetical characters:

```
var qwerty = [['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p'], ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm']];
```

How would I present them in three rows like on a conventional keyboard using JS without resorting to something like this:

```
<input type='button' value='Q' id='bt1'/>
<input type='button' value='W' id='bt2'/>
<input type='button' value='E' id='bt3'/>
<input type='button' value='R' id='bt4'/>
<input type='button' value='T' id='bt5'/>
<input type='button' value='Y' id='bt5'/>
<input type='button' value='U' id='bt7'/>
<input type='button' value='I' id='bt8'/>
<input type='button' value='O' id='bt9'/>
<input type='button' value='P' id='bt10'/>
<br>
<input type='button' value='A' id='bt11'/>
<input type='button' value='S' id='bt12'/>
<input type='button' value='D' id='bt13'/>
<input type='button' value='F' id='bt14'/>
<input type='button' value='G' id='bt15'/>
<input type='button' value='H' id='bt16'/>
<input type='button' value='J' id='bt17'/>
<input type='button' value='K' id='bt18'/>
<input type='button' value='L' id='bt19'/>
<br />
...
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use almost any element to represent them, from divs to buttons and spans. You should go with whatever has more semantic meaning to your solution. If you're aiming for a keyboard then buttons is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use a nested loop:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < qwerty.length; i++) {
   for(var j = 0; j < qwerty[i].length; j++) {
      document.write("<input type='button' value='" + qwerty[i][j] + "' id='bt" + counter++ + "'/>");
   }
   document.write("<br>"); 
}
```

**IF** you're interested, here's a cleaner jQuery solution for adding the new buttons, so you don't have to use `document.write`

```
<div id="qwertDiv" />

var counter = 0, newDiv;
for (var i = 0; i < qwerty.length; i++) {
   newDiv = $("<div />");
   for(var j = 0; j < qwerty[i].length; j++) {
      newDiv.append($("<input type='button' />")
                        .val(qwerty[i][j])
                        .attr("id", "bt" + counter++));
   }
   $("#qwerty").append(newDiv).append("<br>"); 
}
```